# 9patch image as background in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, background-image, android-linearlayout, nine-patch

I have used a 9patch image as background in the Linear Layout. There was no border at all for the image. But when i used it as a background image and debugged the app, there is a white border for the image. Why is it showing the border ? There is nothing wrong with 9patch image when i use it for the button background. I can't understand what exactly the problem is.

My layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:background="@drawable/mehndibg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >  
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDesign"
            android:layout_marginTop="220sp"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_marginLeft="180sp"
            android:background="@drawable/btndesigns"
        />  
    <LinearLayout>
```

The 9patch image is mehndibg.

Comment: can you please post your code here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447318/android-fragments-api-doesnt-show-background-9patch-image-correctly?rq=1

Comment: It could be the background of the parent layout if you have some margin on your layout

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mehndibg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDesign"
            android:layout_marginTop="220sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180sp"
            android:background="@drawable/btndesigns"
             /><lLinearLayout>

Comment: mehndibg is the 9patch image there. I didn't use any margin.

Comment: don't use `sp` for the sizes, use `dp`. try this 1.remove the `leftMargin` 2. And set `wrap_content` for *width and hight* of `LinearLayout`. Could you pls provide a screenshot?